# Why is my page feed returning empty content?

Tags: functions, pages, rss

I am trying to debug why my page feed with is returning empty.

Here's the URL for same,

> http://localhost/design-patterns/code-improvement/feed/

I'm seeing the following output here,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    
    >
<channel>
    <title>
    Comments on: Checking Account   </title>
    <atom:link href="http://localhost/design-patterns/code-improvement/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://localhost/design-patterns</link>
    <description>Just another WordPress site</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Mon, 26 Apr 2021 06:33:50 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <sy:updatePeriod> hourly    </sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency> 1  </sy:updateFrequency>
</channel>
</rss>
```

As you see there are no `<item>` tags present, inspite of there being content in that page.

That is because,

`while ( have_comments() ) :` at `wp-includes\feed-rss2-comments.php`

but the fact is `wp-includes\feed-rss2-comments.php` should never have been called, instead I needed `wp-includes\feed-rss2.php` which calls `while ( have_posts() ) :`

While debugging I reached till `wp-includes\functions.php`

In there the function which was getting called was `do_feed_rss2`. Now according to the [doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_feed_rss2/) if the feed is for comments the `$for_comments`flag should be `true`.

What I observed in my case is it was giving `true` value and since the page had no comments the feed was returning to be empty.

So I started searching for the `do_action` call for `do_feed_rss2` , thinking that is where the value must be getting set from, but all i could find is this,

Can anybody help me finding why is this `$for_comments` flag getting set as `true`?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you testing that `$for_comments` has the value of true? What is the URL of your feed? What are you expecting to see? This doesn't look like a question but an open ended investigation, and there is no code to debug. Disable all plugins and switch to a default theme, test again, then reintroduce plugins and themes untill the issue returns

Comment: @TomJNowell Apologies, I have just started posting here. I have added the required code accordingly and will be checking the plugins one-by-one as per your comment. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: What is `design-patterns/code-improvement/`? Is it a page? A post type archive? If you have created an archive for a post type by creating a custom page template and using `WP_Query` to list the posts, then the feed isn't going to work because you haven't done the archive properly.

Comment: @JacobPeattie It is a page.

Comment: @shellbot97 that's not code, that's XML output, is `/design-patterns/code-improvement/` a post archive or a page template containing a secondary post loop? If it's a page then of course there will be no items, remember the RSS feed uses the main query, if you've thrown away the main query and created a brand new query then there's no reason it would know to pick up that query and use that instead.

Comment: Here's the query which gives me the data, ```SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_posts.ID = '1087') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC``` if I see in here there's a post under ```WP_Post Object [post]``` but instead of iterating through that ```wp-includes\feed-rss2-comments.php``` iterated through ```[comments]``` @TomJNowell

Comment: are you expecting an RSS feed of comments or of posts? It's unclear, you didn't say if you were using a page template for that page or not, or what the code on that page is. By query I mean calls to `get_posts`/`WP_Query`/`query_posts`, raw SQL queries aren't that useful here

Comment: What's likely happened is that `/design-patterns/code-improvement/` is a page, _not_ an archive, so it's showing the comments on the page which is the correct behaviour, and since there are no comments there are no feed items.